# How to debug erratic keyboard problem

Tags: keyboard, touchpad

The problem I'm having is that keyboard is behaving erratically, missing keys on occasions and other times repeating a key forever.

I can tell you the basics. 
This is an HP ProBook 645 laptop with a Synaptics touchpad and touchstick. It running currently 18.10, but the same problem happened with 18.04 (I was hoping that upgrading would solve the problem).

The problem happens with any keyboards, both the builtin, an USB-cord HP keyboard and a Logitech wireless keyboard.

I've seen references to similar problems, but they are either not answered or seem to refer to much older versions of the OS or the kernel.

Now that's the problem I'm facing, it really makes my laptop difficult to use.

I'd like a solution, but I understand that it is difficult with the information I can provide right now, so I'd like to ask instead for how to debug this problem: what packages to install, what to check, what traces to turn on, what logs to look at.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In `/dev/input/by-path` you should be able to find a link to your keyboard, in my case it's named:`pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:7.1:1.0-event-kbd`.

You can maybe try to `$sudo cat /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:7.1:1.0-event-kbd`
this can indicate you at least when a key is pressed and released from the "hardware" pov.
In short if it keeps printing while the key is unpressed it means that from the low level pov the keyboard is still sending data. (you can also use files under /sys/kernel/debug/hid/DEVICE/event (device is matching `lsusb` output))

The strange thing with your problem is that it happens with any keyboard so does not seem to be keyboard hardware related...

Does this problem happen without running Xserver ? Maybe you could also just to see if the problem keeps happening.

Actually to be honest your problem can be related to numerous reasons, I advice you to read this [document](https://www.x.org/wiki/Events/XDC2015/Program/tissoires_input_debug_tools.html) which will give you some directions to conduct your research.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to follow your advice and post more details back.

Comment: @jsantander any update ?

Comment: Had some litle time to apply the methods and tools in your document. When keys start repeating wildly, the show in `evemu-record`.